# Using table data, show location on google maps

Tags: php, google-maps

On my page I have a number of users showing, each one has a postcode.

Is it possible to somehow show an iframe of that location on Google maps using PHP? I've tried googling and stack overflow for an answer and this is the best I've found only it's a link as opposed to embedding it on the page?

[How to convert an address into a Google Maps Link (NOT MAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300838/how-to-convert-an-address-into-a-google-maps-link-not-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for PHP. Just create an iframe pointing to https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=POSTCODE

```
<iframe src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=SW1A+2AA" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
```

Comment: Im just getting an empty 'iframe' @Tim Fountain

Comment: You'll need to set a width and height as well

Comment: haha yeah I tried that too, in my source it shows fine <iframe src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=SK94PQ" width="200" height="200"></iframe>

Comment: I'm not sure if you are missing the http:// from your example or whether it was stripped out from the comment. But if the URL works in a browser it will work in an iframe. So see if you can work out what is different

Comment: No luck, not even working in jsfiddle... @Tim Fountain http://jsfiddle.net/GtjvL/

Comment: Sorry, yes you need to add an additional query param. Try: `<iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=SW1A+2AA&amp;output=embed"></iframe>​​​​​​​​​​​`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [google maps api](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/1bfda7726614473b) and consider using php to dynamically build the url.