# How to convert address to White Pages link

Tags: url

Is there a way, given address, name or phone number, to generate a link to White Pages that looks up that info? This question is really similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300838/how-to-convert-an-address-into-a-google-maps-link-not-map), except White Pages instead of Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the link to send your request setting the parameters on the URL.

If you are looking for a business:

`http://www.whitepages.com/business?key=*name*&where=*where*`

http://www.whitepages.com/business?key=Google&where=California

If you are looking for a person:

`http://www.whitepages.com/name/*first_name*-*last_name*/*where*`

http://www.whitepages.com/name/John-Smith/California-City

If you are looking for a phone:

`http://www.whitepages.com/phone/9-999-999-9999`

http://www.whitepages.com/phone/9-999-999-9999

If you are looking for a street:

`http://www.whitepages.com/search/FindNearby?utf8=%E2%9C%93&street=*street+name*&where=*where*`

http://www.whitepages.com/search/FindNearby?utf8=%E2%9C%93&street=Lake+View&where=California

Hope that helps you!

Thanks!