# Create link from a text address box to automatically go to Google Maps Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to create a link that takes me to the address' Google Street View. I found this:
[How to convert an address into a Google Maps Link (NOT MAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300838/how-to-convert-an-address-into-a-google-maps-link-not-map)

The solution for the question above was:
http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003

Is there a parameter I can add to the link to make it automatically go to Street View?

I am currently using the arcgis World Geocoder in my application, so I will try to pass the address entered into the link to google Street View.

```
    function locate() {
      map.graphics.clear();
      var address = {
        "SingleLine": dom.byId("address").value
      };
      locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
      var options = {
        address: address
      }
      locator.addressToLocations(options);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done

here is an example form google docs

```
 var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
var mapOptions = {
  center: fenway,
  zoom: 14
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var panoramaOptions = {
  position: fenway,
  pov: {
    heading: 34,
    pitch: 10
  }
};
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
```

[here is the result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple?hl=FR)

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl=FR

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at this. I am actually using the ArcGIS API for Javascript for my main map. I just want to provide a link to Google Maps Street View for the address that would take me out of my application.

Comment: Sure no problem. I was really looking for an alternative to embedding a streetview map into my webpage. Google's TOS will not allow us to use Street View because my content is behind a password protected page (not publicly available). That's why I was looking into some kind of URL that I could attach parameters to in order to go to streetview.

Comment: aha. ah well. does the last line of that code not work?

Comment: i just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url looks useful!