# mailto: link equivalent for address

Tags: html

I was wondering if there is an equivalent of "mailto:" for physical addresses. Ideally, it would launch the default maps application on the user's mobile/table device with the address entered by default, just like how "tel:" works.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=term
```

term would be the adress

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300838/how-to-convert-an-address-into-a-google-maps-link-not-map)

Comment: Close. It would launch Google Maps, not the default application. Similarly, [`http://maps.apple.com/?q=`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) will launch iOS Maps. There is no URL scheme that will launch the default app yet.

Comment: I already have a google maps iframe on my page. I just wanted to provide a generic link also since some people may be forced to download Google maps if they don't already have it on their phone.